# Best way to make Android app execute python script on a remote computer and return a string output

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm making an Android app for personal use. The goal is to give an input on my phone, send the input to a Python script on my PC, and return the output as a string.

What is the best way to make it connect to my Windows on PC, execute the python file, and return the result as simple string output?

Comment: Have the app write something to Firebase, have the Python script monitoring Firebase and react, then write back to Firebase which the app is monitoring

Comment: you might need to implement a webserver to fulfill your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the app write something to Firebase, have the Python script monitoring Firebase and react, then write back to Firebase which the app is monitoring

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Comment: That's a good idea! I'm already utilizing firebase storage for this app, so I could integrate firebase database as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH to run commands on a remote computer
for this purpose there are several libraries in Java, for example, you can use [JSH Library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

it's a simple example:

```
public static String executeRemoteCommand(
                   String username,
                   String password,
                   String hostname,
                   int port) throws Exception {     

  JSch jsch = new JSch();
   Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
   session.setPassword(password);

   // Avoid asking for key confirmation
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
   session.setConfig(prop);

   session.connect();

   // SSH Channel
   ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");      
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

   // Execute command
   channelssh.setCommand("ls");
   channelssh.connect();        
   channelssh.disconnect();

   return baos.toString();
 }
```

Resource link: [SSH, execute remote commands with Android](https://eridem.net/android-tip-021-ssh-execute-remote-commands-with-android)